# How to set two pseudo classes on an element?

Tags: css

This works:

```
#sList li:visible {
    background: rgba(255,255,136,0.5);
}
```

This works:

```
#sList li:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: rgba(255,255,136,0.5);
}
```

This doesn't:

```
#sList li:visible:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: rgba(255,255,136,0.5);
}
```

Hmm... any help?

**EDIT**: To elaborate — I have a search field that — on `.keyup` — filters a `<ul>` below it.

Think a faux-Google Instant Search type thing. I want the backgrounds to be staggered in color. They are when the page loads, but as soon as you start typing and elements begin to be eliminated from the list the zebra striping background pattern goes away and becomes inconsistent because certain elements are now hidden. I wanted to do something where on every `.keyup` of the search field the zebra striping is re-applied so that the list remains consistently striped.

Make sense?

Comment: Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uxuleg/edit#html,live) for anyone who wants to test it.

Comment: What is the purpose of giving an invisible element a background-color?

Comment: @Mikey It's giving visible `<li>` elements a color.

Comment: What are you [actually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) trying to do? Implement zebra striping while making sure it still works when some `li` are hidden?

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-of-type` only considers the **element's tag type**. There is no way to make this pseudo-selector select the *n*th matched element.

Also, `:visible` is not a valid [pseudo-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes).

Answer (score 0):

According to [SitePoint's list of pseudoclasses](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses), there is no :visible.  Let's use an example with [:hover](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover) instead.

### [demo](http://jsbin.com/uxuleg/2/edit)

When we have a list, we can use the two classes to say highlight it if, and only if, the element is an odd child AND hovered.  Notice how the ipsum's don't highlight when hovered, but the Lorem's do.

```css
#sList3 li:hover:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: rgba(255,255,136,0.5);
}
```

```html
<ul id="sList3">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add `display:none` to one of the list elements, and you'll see that the resulting effect is not desired: http://jsbin.com/uxuleg/3/edit.